# Is there a way to execute some task after a python package was installed according to some entry_point defined?

Tags: python, distutils

I want to know if there is a way to register some special entry_point and executes some task when the package is installed and has that entry_point defined, pretty much like console_scripts, I imagine is distutils the one that execute the tasks,but there is a way to register more tasks according to some entry_point?

At the end I want to execute something like a post-install task but not defined in the package but in another one.

The way I'm doing this right now is to monitor the pkg_resources.iter_entry_points every x seconds, and reload the package pkg_resources to get the new entry_points and do the action when someone defines one new, I'm doing this in a daemon, but it seems that there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create your own entry points similar to the console scripts. You can define the entry points as anything you want and can use `pkg_resources.iter_entry_points` method to act upon that definition, which will be called in the same manner as console_scripts. 
Here are [two](http://www.turbogears.org/1.0/docs/UsingEntryPoints.html) [good](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2010/01/06/zest-releaser-entry-points.html) resources on this subject.

Comment: I know I can create my own entry_point and get them with pkg_resources. What I'm asking is if there is a way to execute a task immediately the package is installed according to some entry_point. The way to discover entry_points is after the package was installed, is there any way to tell to distutils "hey, every time you get a package with this entry_point execute this other task"?